# Personalizar texto layout android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

¿Como puedo personalizar los TextView? Mi idea es la de que algunas partes del layout se vean mas que otros para hacer mas enfasis en ciertas partes del layout. Basicamente mi idea es la que sale en la imagen que adjunto, pero implementandolo en mi app.

[image: Idea]`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/saldoLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/saldoTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/saldo"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/letra"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/activityStockLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/saldoLinearLayout"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/activityStockLinearLayoutLeft"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activityStockValue_textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="10.763,30" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activityStockName_textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            tools:text="IBEX 35" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activityStockIniciales_textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="^IBEX" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/activityStockLinearLayoutRight"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activityStockLogoLinearLayoutRight"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activityStockValuesLinearLayoutRight"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/graphLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/activityStockLinearLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

</LinearLayout>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo que utilizes los estilos materiales predefinidos de Android para evitar problemas. Pero tambíen puedes definir el tuyo propio, para ello puedes modificar los siguientes parametros:

```
android:textStyle="normal|bold|italic"
```

Con ello podrás tener la letra en negrita o cursiva. Además puedes cambiar la fuente a alguna predefinida con:

```
android:fontFamily:"sans-serif"
```

y todas sus variantes.
También puedes descargar alguna fuente en internet e incluirla en tu código:

```
texto = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.tvDefault);
    //Definicion de nuestro propio estilo de fuente
    String font_path = "font/AlexBrush-Regular.ttf";
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(rootview.getContext().getAssets(),font_path);
    texto.setTypeface(tf);
```

Por último, solo te quedaría jugar con el color.

```
android:textColor = "@color/colorPrimary"
```

Los cuales podrás modificar en el archivo xml situado en values/colors.xml

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar los atributos en un `TextView`:

```
<item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
<item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
<item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
```

La especificación del tamaño se recomienda usar unidad `sp` que es escalable si el usuario en preferencia del sistema define el tamaño de letra.

#### Estilo de letra Material Design

Se puede establecer un estilo que engloba, tamaño, tipografia y grossor, usando `android:textAppearance` el siguiente enlace hay los referentes [Tipos de letra Material Design](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/typography.html#typography-roboto)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Su uso**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="location"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />
```

Los que puedes usar:

- Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display4
- Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display3
- Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display2
- Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1
- Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline
- Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title
- Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title.Inverse
- Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead
- Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead.Inverse
- Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2
- Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1
- Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption
- Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Menu
- Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button

Answer (score 0):

Vengo a enseñarte otra manera super facil, que te va a volar la cabeza 
Utilizando esta [dependencia](https://github.com/TheBrownArrow/CustomTypeface?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=5369) vas a ser capaz de customiser cada texto de cada cosa que desees de la manera mas facil posible , solo buscas las fuentes que usaras en internet y listo, los declaras como te enseñan en la dependencia.

Yo lo utilizo siempre y tengo algo como esto por ejemplo para un texto:

```
<com.thebrownarrow.customfont.CustomFontTextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvRestaurantName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:text="Restaurant"
                        app:custom_typeface="fonts/estandar.ttf"/>
```